# Client server basic communication with socket C

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

i made a program, both server and client side, which allow me to send message from client to server. It works locally. I tipe in the client terminal `./client "message"` and `message` appear on the server terminal. So everything works fine. OK, now i want to take it "online", i mean i want to send message between two debian machine emulated through virtualbox. What to do? I think it's important to adjust the IP address into the right one. Atm i'm using, in the client code,  `127.0.0.1` which is LOCALHOST. In the client so i have to put the server IP? Which means Server require static IP?

Comment: What is your specific problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the server IP, which can change if it's not static. You also have to consider the port number, and whether it's open or not on either end of the connection. Otherwise, the network will stop the traffic flowing through to and from the client. A static IP will be best, but you might also consider allowing the user to enter an IP address in the command, for example

`./ client "message" -ip="192.168.0.1:25534"`

This way you can use it on multiple machines, if necessary, and you can cater to the change in IP by just getting them to enter it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, actually it works as i've intended. Your tips are good to develope further features. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Client changes:

Configurable server IP and port. You can do this through command line parameters, environment variables or a configuration file. If the target OS is MS Windows you could also opt to do it via registry settings.

Server changes:

When you `bind` the server socket to an address you need to specify either a fixed IP or `INADDR_ANY`. If you bind to `127.0.0.1` the server will only accept connections from the same machine. `INADDR_ANY` will bind the socket to all IP addresses of the server (could be more than one).
You should also make the port number configurable.

Comment: How can i reach the server virtual machine from another net (i mean even from another city ecc..)? The server IP is `10.0.2.20` but i think it regards the virtualbox Nat Network.  What IP i have to write in the client code? How can i find it?

Comment: @ducajack I guess you could create an IP tunnel on your host machine to your virtual server. The remote clients would connect to a port on your host, using it's IP address and the tunnel would forward the IP packets to your virtual server.